# How to Access Google Plus API from Different Activity

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I am having trouble with the Google Plus Android API. I have a new activity, and I want to access the User's name and other details. How do I do that? I understand how to do it in the Sign In activity, but how do I access user information in this new activity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation on signing in](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in):

> When the user has successfully signed in, your onConnected handler will be called. At this point, you are able to retrieve the user’s account name or make authenticated requests.

It looks like there's a [specific method](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_profile_information_for_a_signed_in_user) for retrieving the signed-in user's information once sign in has been completed: `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson`

> Use the Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson method to request profile information the currently signed in user.
>
> You can call the getCurrentPerson method after the GoogleApiClient is connected:

```
@Override
public void onConnected() {
  ...
  if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
    Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
    String personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage();
    String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
  }
}
```